# for loop in swift step by step?

Tags: swift

I have the following array with urls:

```
let KStorePlayURL = [
    https://source.s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/ENVOI/2018/07/19/ATASTEOFDANCE_S1_EP3.mp4,                
    https://source.s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/ENVOI/2018/05/23/ATasteOfDance_S1E1_Episode.mp4,                         
    https://source.s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/ENVOI/2018/05/23/ATasteOfDance_S1E1_Episode.mp4,
    https://source.s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/ENVOI/2018/05/23/ATasteOfDance_S1E1_Episode.mp4
]
```

How can I get the URLs one after the other in the for loop? Also when one video is played and followed by other videos in this Bitmovin player?

Here is the code I have already tried:

```
@objc func setUpPlayerVideos1() {

   print(KStorePlayURL)

   for i in 0..<KStorePlayURL.count {

      let streamURL = URL(string: KStorePlayURL[i])

      playlist.append(PlaylistItem(url: streamURL!, title: "player"))
      // Create player based with a default configuration
      let player = BitmovinPlayer()

      // Create player view and pass the player instance to it
      let playerView = BMPBitmovinPlayerView(player: player, frame: .zero)

      // Listen to player events
      player.add(listener: self)

      playerView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleHeight, .flexibleWidth]
      playerView.frame = view.bounds

      view.addSubview(playerView)
      view.bringSubview(toFront: playerView)

      // store the reference to the player
      self.Bitmovinplayer = player

   }
   // Start the playlist
   playNextItem()
}
```

Comment: The for loop is not waiting for the end of the video. It just loop, creating each time a new player with one the the URL and replacing the current one with it.

Comment: what changes to be made in code to get better output

Comment: Does your player manages playlists of URLs? If not, you need to detect yourself the end of a video, then go to the next one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't be using a for-loop, because you are going to be overriding the player in each iteration. What you need to do is fill the `playlist`using a for-loop or a more functional style like this :

```
KStorePlayURL.forEach { urlString in
    //Make sure that the url address is correct
    guard let streamURL = URL(string: urlString) else {
        fatalError("Error in stream url")
    }
    playlist.append(PlaylistItem(url: streamURL!, title: "player"))
}
```

Here I am supposing that `KStorePlayURL` is an array of strings:

```
let KStorePlayURL = [
    "https://source.s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/ENVOI/2018/07/19/ATASTEOFDANCE_S1_EP3.mp4",
    "https://source.s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/ENVOI/2018/05/23/ATasteOfDance_S1E1_Episode.mp4",
    "https://source.s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/ENVOI/2018/05/23/ATasteOfDance_S1E1_Episode.mp4",
    "https://source.s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/ENVOI/2018/05/23/ATasteOfDance_S1E1_Episode.mp4"
]
```

Your final code should look like this:

```
@objc func setUpPlayerVideos1() {

    KStorePlayURL.forEach { urlString in
        guard let streamURL = URL(string: urlString) else {
            fatalError("Error in stream url")
        }
        playlist.append(PlaylistItem(url: streamURL!, title: "player"))
    }

        let player = BitmovinPlayer()

        // Create player view and pass the player instance to it
        let playerView = BMPBitmovinPlayerView(player: player, frame: .zero)

        // Listen to player events
        player.add(listener: self)

        playerView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleHeight, .flexibleWidth]
        playerView.frame = view.bounds

        view.addSubview(playerView)
        view.bringSubview(toFront: playerView)

        // store the reference to the player
        self.Bitmovinplayer = player

    }
    // Start the playlist
    playNextItem()
}
```

You can find a complete sample code for playing a playlist with the bitmovin player [here](https://github.com/bitmovin/bitmovin-player-ios-samples/blob/9298c33623e4cb75e9ab50062a0208dc2e7c55ca/BasicPlaylist/BasicPlaylist/ViewController.swift).